# ManyToMany: No match in a join table

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many, h2

I have a bilateral ManyToMany relationship between Employee (owning side) and Telephone.
When I post an employee with telephones everything works and is saved into three tables (emloyees, telephones, employee_telephone).
However when I post a telephone with employees the entities are saved into each own table but there is no match in a join table (employee_telephone).

Employee entity

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Employee {

    private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "employee_telephone", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "telephone_id"))
    Set<Telephone> telephones = new HashSet<>();

    public void addTelephone(Telephone telephone) {
        this.telephones.add(telephone);
        telephone.getEmployees().add(this);
    }
}
```

Telephone entity:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Telephone {

    private Integer number;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "telephones", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();

    public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employees.add(employee);
        employee.getTelephones().add(this);
    }
}
```

Telephone controller:

```
@PostMapping("/telephones")
public Telephone addTelephone(@RequestBody Telephone telephone) {
    return telephoneManager.save(telephone);
}
```

Employee controller:

```
@PostMapping("/employees")
    public Employee saveEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        return employeeManager.save(employee);  
    }
```

Employee manager:

```
  @Service
public class EmployeeManager {
    
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    public EmployeeManager(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository) {
        super();
        this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    }

    public Employee save(Employee employee){
        Employee employee2 = new Employee();
        employee2.setName(employee.getName());

        Telephone telephone = new Telephone();
        telephone.addEmployee(employee2);
        
        return employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }
}
```

Telephone manager:

```
@Service
public class TelephoneManager {

    TelephoneRepository telephoneRepository;

    @Autowired
    public TelephoneManager(TelephoneRepository telephoneRepository) {
        super();
        this.telephoneRepository = telephoneRepository;
    }
    
    public Telephone save(Telephone telephone) {
        Telephone telephone2 = new Telephone();
        telephone2.setNumber(telephone.getNumber());

        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.addTelephone(telephone2);
        
        return telephoneRepository.save(telephone);
    }
}
```

JSON I send from Postman from http://localhost:8080/telephones

```
{
 "number": 12345,
 "employees" : [
    {
        "name" : "max1"
    },
      {
        "name" : "max2"
    }
]
}
```

JSON I send from Postman from: http://localhost:8080/employees

```
{
"name": "hela", 
 "telephones" : [
    {
        "number" : 123
    },

      {
        "number" : 456
    }
]
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Please add the relevant code where you create the `Employee` entity object, and populate it.  You probably are missing some set operations, but more cannot be said until we have seen your code.

Comment: Hello Tim, I updated my post, it is ok now?

Comment: Doesn't help, my request above still stands.

Comment: hmmm this is everything I have (appart from repositories). Sorry don' understand now :(
Or do you mean I should edit saveEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) method or addTelephone(@RequestBody Telephone telephone) method?

Comment: I edited my code with some methods, but it still doesn't work. I can save telephone with a few employees but there is no match in the join table

Comment: Looks better, thanks.  Will take a look ASAP.

Comment: Your `save()` methods don't seem to make much sense, as you are creating empty objects for the other side of the relationship.